# Jira like autocomplete for textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, autocomplete

I want to implement Jira like auto complete behavior for one of my pet project.
Check following screenshot.

[image]

I have searched hard for any existing plugin that could able to deliver it but couldn't find anyone.

I have tried following things ([JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/jkkkv1ym/)):

- Add `textarea` and `input`(hidden initially) field elements.
- Bind a `keyPress` event on `textarea`
- Capture `@` key and showing `input` field enabled with `jQuery#autocomplete` plugin with list of users

HTML:

```
<div class='span12'>
    <textarea id='comments' class='span12'></textarea>
    <input id='users' class='span12 hide' />
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
    var users = [
        "Ram",
        "Ramesh",
        "Rakesh",
        "Rahul",
        "Abhi",
        "Karan"
    ];
    $('#comments').on('keypress', function(e){
      if(e.keyCode === 64) {
        $( "#users" ).removeClass('hide');
        $( "#users" ).autocomplete({
          source: users
        });
      }
    });
});
```

My questions are:

- How can we trigger `@text` to show auto-complete list with `text` as selected?
- After selecting the user, how we can insert that user name in the `textarea`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following are the three JavaScript plugins I found which serves the purpose I am looking for:

- [jQuery-textcomplete.js](http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/)
- [At.js](http://ichord.github.io/At.js/)
- [triggeredAutocomplete.js](https://github.com/Hawkers/triggeredAutocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

A great implementation with a UI just like this is [jquery.mentionsInput](http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/).

It works with arrays of objects to auto-suggest as well as content fetched via AJAX requests. It requires jQuery and underscore.js and supports MSIE 8 and better.

Of particular note is it that exports links to usernames using a simple Markdown style markup, storing internal ID's alongside the @username mention. This means you can easily parse the text to do things like trigger events based on who is mentioned and means you can display real, human readable names in text but still correlate them with unique user ID's internally.

Any Markdown library can convert it to plain text if you need to just store or display the result as plain text.